# redirect the session timeout page in apache shiro

Tags: java, jsf, session-timeout, shiro

I have `login.xhtml`, `managePage.xhtml` and `sessionTimeout.xhtml`. I want to redirect the sessionTimeout page when the session is time out. But it redirects to the login page whenever session is time out.

In the web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/sessionTimeout.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
```

in shiro.ini

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /faces/loginPage.xhtml
authc.successUrl  = /faces/registerPage.xhtml
# ------------------------  
  ....
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[urls]  
/faces/protected/* = authc
```

1. I want to redirect the sessionTimeout page when session is time
   out.
2. I would like to know what different between
   `/faces/protected/*` and `/faces/protected/**`. I used one(*). It
   works.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking on some SessionException. Something like [ExpiredSessionException](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/ExpiredSessionException.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add something like:

```
[urls]
/faces/sessionTimeout.xhtml = anon
/faces/protected/** = authc
```

The session timeout page is unprotected and it shouldn't redirect you to login.
Or if the real path is without /faces:

```
[urls]
/sessionTimeout.xhtml = anon
/protected/** = authc
```

As for question two: the ** syntax is ant-style. It means everything in the directory, plus all below.
So for example:

/foo/* matches on /foo/bar.html, but not on /foo/foo/bar.html.

When using /foo/** it matches on both.

For more information, check out http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html in the section "Patterns".

Comment: I login by `loginPage` and go to the `managePage`. When the session is time out in `managePage`, it should redirect to the `sessionTimeout` page.